# is there any way to convert this python code into php

Tags: python, php, code-translation, transpiler, code-transformation

what i need to accomplish is to reach a way in which i can convert the basics on any python code into php functions and conditions and so on

```
  def BitmapHoles(strArr):
    bitmap = {}
    for i in range(len(strArr)):
        for j in range(len(strArr[i])):
            bitmap[(i,j)] = int(strArr[i][j])
    //
    hole_count = 0
    hole = set()
    checked = set()
    flag = True
    
    for i in range(len(strArr)):
        for j in range(len(strArr[i])):
            stack = [(i,j)]
            while stack:
                coords = stack.pop()
                if coords not in checked:
                    checked.add(coords)
                    if bitmap[coords] == 0 and coords not in hole:
                        hole.add(coords)
                        if flag == True:
                            hole_count += 1
                            flag = False
                        if coords[0] - 1 >= 0 and (coords[0]-1,coords[1]) not in checked:
                            stack.append((coords[0]-1,coords[1]))
                        if coords[0] + 1 < len(strArr) and (coords[0]+1,coords[1]) not in checked:
                            stack.append((coords[0]+1,coords[1]))
                        if coords[1] - 1 >= 0 and (coords[0],coords[1]-1) not in checked:
                            stack.append((coords[0],coords[1]-1))
                        if coords[1] + 1 < len(strArr[coords[0]]) and (coords[0],coords[1]+1) not in checked:
                            stack.append((coords[0],coords[1]+1))
            flag = True
            //
    return hole_count
```

Comment: Well, you could write a transpiler for this. Parse python into AST, massage as needed (to handle python specific things, like list comprehensions), render AST as PHP. Or you could pay someone to convert code.

Comment: You want to convert _this_ python code to php, or you want to have a program to convert _any_ python code to php? Your title asks one thing but then the description talks about something a bit different. The first is just a case of spending some time rewriting the code. The second is a big, complicated project which is far too broad for a stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAI has an AI to convert code from one language to another. I believe it supports PHP and Python. I have used this tool and it converts the code very accuratly.
Here's a link to an example OpenAI has on their website: https://beta.openai.com/examples/default-translate-code

Comment: not available in my country sir

Comment: @ibrahimkhalaf try accessing it via a vpn

Comment: I offer two tools, on my website to help.  Fuzzy logic is a great tool, but there are others.  On my pages, I also provide links to open source libraries that can help.

Also, the problem is more complicated then you suggest, and you may also want to consider trying to just interact PHP with Python.  But, if you find more string replace helps, we offer two different versions to help with the process: https://properprogramming.com/tools/converters/python-3-to-php-converter-version-2-online/

Comment: https://github.com/0xpayne/gpt-migrate – this tool works on top of the OpenAI API and can be very helpful with small-ish projects or chunks of bigger ones.